# Изменить список 2

Tags: python

Новый вопрос на основе списков. Есть значения a, b:

```
a = [12, 71, 121, 163, 200, 243, 259]
b = [139, 132 135, 131, 137, 132, 134]
```

"a" соответвует порядковому номеру значения в списке, а "b" - значение которое приходится на этот номер. Как из a, b получить:

```
с = [...0,0,0,139,0,0,0,.....0,0,0,132,0,0,0,...]
```

где 139 находится под номером 12 в списке, а 132 под номером 71

Comment: Ладно, скопирую сюда )

Comment: @Jack_oS Там было про `numpy`, а тут про списки. Хотя, конечно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант через списочное сокращение и с использованием словаря, данные генерируются "последовательно":

```
a = [12, 71, 121, 163, 200, 243, 259]
b = [139, 132, 135, 131, 137, 132, 134]

d = dict(zip(a,b))
c = [d[i] if i in d else 0 for i in range(max(a)+1)]
```

Не очень понимаю, зачем вам `nan`, ведь в чистом питоне нет `nan`, а если вы хотите работать с `numpy`, то и методы лучше использовать от `numpy` и его типы данных, а не питоновские списки. Со списками лучше использовать `None` уж тогда.

Comment: можно использовать `get`: `d.get(i, 0)`

Comment: @Valent А, понятно. Ну вы можете что угодно вместо 0 в данный код подставить.

Comment: @Valent Так у вас список, или `numpy.array`? Поменяйте `range` на `np.arange` и ошибка уйдёт.

Comment: @Valent Так потому что если у вас такие значения именно в `a`, а не в `b`, то ведь `a` - это индексы элементов, а не значения. Как вы предлагаете интерпретировать дробные значения в качестве порядковых номеров элементов? Я могу добавить округление, это не вопрос. Но вы точно этого хотите?